# Booting of Xen Hypervisor on ubuntu 16.04.03 got stuck

Tags: xen

we have installed the Xen Software and changed the GRUB configuration, following the standard guide on ubuntu forums.

While rebooting the server, hypervisor and server did not come up and no error logs are displayed. tried searching in google but it relates to "BIOS" settings and no more resolution. BIOS settings are as per the standard.

Since we are stuck from 1 week,some important APIs have to tested.

Please help us in the solving the issue.

As per "OS Screen" message appears below:-

loading Xen 4.6-amd64...
warning: no console will be available to os
loading linux 4.4.0.87-generic 
loading initial ramdisk.

Comment: Update your BIOS and that should fix the issue.